# Jest: Unexpected token on default export

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I have my jest config setup well for all cases. Successfully run over 200+ tests. However, one of my tests recently failed with this error.
`Unexpected token, expected ;`

This happens when in my index.js file for a particular component (let's say Header), I'm exporting my component like this

`export default from './Header';`

rather than

`import Header from './Header';
export default Header;`

Answer (score -1):

`export ... from` is not standard and requires babel [transform-export-extensions](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-export-extensions/)

I think you are using this because it's working in your sources outside of the tests, but your tests are not transpilled the same way as your sources.

You can either don't use this syntax in your tests or transpile your tests with babel.